# Unnecessary Uncaught, unspecified "error" event

Tags: javascript, node.js

In node.js, when I call:

```
throw 'no handler error';
```

when the error happens, I get this message from node.js:

```
events.js:87
      throw Error('Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.');
            ^
Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.
    at Error (native)
    at emit (events.js:87:13)
```

How can Node.js not retrieve the message 'no handler error' ? I get the same problem when I call '`throw new Error('no handler error');`'

How do I create an error message that can retrieved upon invocation? Seems crazy that node.js would allow me to define the error message without ever being able to see it later?

Comment: this might be irrelevant but have you seen this? - https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4847    
might solve the error. Who knows. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

The throw should be like :

```
throw new Error('No handler error');
```

**BUT :**
You should only throw `fatal` errors... For other errors, you should return a callback with the error :

```
function dummy(next) {
  err = True;
  if(err) return next(new Error('No handler error'));
  return next(null, data);
}
```

or emit an "error" event on an EventEmitter

A great informations about when you have to throw, when do you use a callback or an event !

https://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors

Answer (score 2):

You are throwing a string instead of an error, you should probably do something like this:

```
throw new NoHandlerError();
```

And define your `NoHandlerError` somewhere in your library depending on how you are structuring it.

**EDIT** Upon a good comment suggestion made by @enl8enmentnow

```
throw new Error ("no handle error");
```

Comment: Better would be: throw new Error ("no handle error");

Comment: Added your suggestion. Thanks.